# Sparql get "is dbo:parent of" records from Dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to get children of persons. Some persons have children listed in "dbo:child", others have them listed as "is dbo:parent of"

Here are examples of the two types

1. https://dbpedia.org/page/Elizabeth_II
2. https://dbpedia.org/page/George_V

For the first one I can pull child records off as follows:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elizabeth_II> 
dbo:child?child 
}
```

For the second it's a bit harder as I think I have to find other records which point to George_V. I'm struggling to find anything that works, this is the best I can come up with

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
  ?person a              dbo:Person ;
   dbo:parent [dbo:Person dbr:George_V] 
}
limit 10
```

What's the best way to do this? Is there a way I can combine the two approaches?

Comment: he second for sure doesn't work, it should be just `dbo:parent dbr:George_V .` - combining both works for example by using a SPARQL property path for example: `SELECT *
WHERE
{
dbr:George_V dbo:child|^dbo:parent  ?child }`

Comment: Thanks SELECT distinct * WHERE { dbr:Elizabeth_II dbo:child|^dbo:parent  ?child } and SELECT distinct * WHERE { dbr:George_V dbo:child|^dbo:parent  ?child } both return what I want

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that solves the problem. Note, you have to look at the data for familial properties (relationship types) and then explore regarding data quality.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?royal ?ancestor
WHERE {
        { 
          <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Charles,_Prince_of_Wales>
                    <http://dbpedia.org/property/father>+ ?ancestor .
        }
        UNION
        {
          <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Charles,_Prince_of_Wales>
                    <http://dbpedia.org/property/mother>+ ?ancestor .
        }
        BIND ( <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Charles,_Prince_of_Wales> as ?royal )
      }
```

[Live DBpedia Query Solution Link](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Froyal%20%3Fancestor%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCharles%2C_Prince_of_Wales%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2Ffather%3E%2B%20%3Fancestor%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCharles%2C_Prince_of_Wales%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2Fmother%3E%2B%20%3Fancestor%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCharles%2C_Prince_of_Wales%3E%20as%20%3Froyal%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=0&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on).

Alternatively, which is closer to your original property preference (i.e., `dbo:parent`), here is another property-paths based example.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?royal ?ancestor ?ancestorName
WHERE {
        <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elizabeth_II>
              dbo:parent* ?ancestor     . 
        ?ancestor 
              foaf:name   ?ancestorName . 
        FILTER (LANG(?ancestorName) = "en")                

        BIND ( <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elizabeth_II> as ?royal )
      }
```

[Live Query Results Link](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Froyal%20%3Fancestor%20%3FancestorName%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FElizabeth_II%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aparent*%20%3Fancestor%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fancestor%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FancestorName%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28%3FancestorName%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FElizabeth_II%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aparent*%20%3Fancestor%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fancestor%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FancestorName%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28%3FancestorName%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FElizabeth_II%3E%20as%20%3Froyal%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=0&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on).

We are working on a new DBpedia release that should have increased quality regarding this kind of information.

Finally, a tweak to some earlier suggestions (posted as comments).

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?royal ?child
WHERE { 
        dbr:George_V  dbo:child+|^dbo:parent+  ?child .
        BIND ( dbr:George_V AS ?royal )
      }
```

[Live DBpedia Query Link](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Froyal+%3Fchild%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++dbr%3AGeorge_V+++++dbo%3Achild%2B%7C%5Edbo%3Aparent%2B+%3Fchild+.%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++BIND+%28dbr%3AGeorge_V+AS+%3Froyal%29+%0D%0A+++++++++++++%7D&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on).